# Conect a microphone to a pc via wifi connection

Tags: microphone

Is there any way to conect 4 microphones or more to a pc via wifi in realtime, control each one and mix all together?

Comment: Wi-fi would be a very unreliable medium to stream a recording. A wireless set like Rory suggested would be much more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can transport multiple four microphone signals wirelessly, but not via wifi:

You'll need either:

- a wireless receiver that can accept multiple channels - so you can pass the different sound channels to your mixer application (whether that be a DAW or dedicated mixer app)

or

- 4 wireless receivers that feed 4 inputs on your sound card, that you then mix as before.

Cost-wise, they seem to be about the same.

The reasons you cannot use wifi are many but one simple one is that to move those little packets of sound across a network requires a very predictable delivery times, as a (highly) shared medium, wifi cannot deliver that.

Its a pity as it'd be great to load an app on a phone, plug in a mic and be live on a mixing board

Comment: I'm guessing the hardware setup for this and it would probably be 4x lavalier mics going into 4x Zaxcom wireless transceivers running Zaxnet. From the receiving end of the transceiver, the 4 wireless will go into an audio interface going into your PC running Boom Recorder or a DAW. You can control the faders on your interface, in your DAW or get a Zaxcom Mix8 to control the wireless preamp in realtime. @dom it would be best if you could give more details as to how you want to run your setup cos it can be a lot simpler if you didn't have to record into a PC.